# ContextMenuService.Placement doesn't work in setter for MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, button, mvvm, contextmenu

I have gone through some of the previous similar questions, but am still having issues with the ContextMenuService.Placement. Please suggest.

It worked fine when I followed this approach

```
<Button x:Name="btn" Content="button"  Click="b_Click" >
        <Button.ContextMenu >
            <ContextMenu   >
                <MenuItem Header="Open" Command="{Binding OnOpen}" ></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Close" Command="{Binding OnClose}"></MenuItem>                    
            </ContextMenu>
        </Button.ContextMenu>
    </Button>

    private void be_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
            btn.ContextMenu.PlacementTarget = btn;//Like this
            btn.ContextMenu.Placement = PlacementMode.Top;//Like this
            btn.ContextMenu.DataContext = btn.DataContext;
            btn.ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;            
            }
```

But it doesn't work with MVVM pattern.

```
<Button x:Name="btn" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" ContextMenuService.IsEnabled="False">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Click">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="ContextMenu.IsOpen">
                                    <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="True"/>
                                </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="ContextMenu.IsEnabled">
                                    <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="True"/>
                                </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu Name="AddReportContextMenu" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                         <MenuItem Header="Open" Command="{Binding OnOpen}" ></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Close" Command="{Binding OnClose}"></MenuItem>                    
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
    </Button>
```

I tried adding it in setter like this

```
<Setter Property="ContextMenu.PlacementTarget" Value="{Binding ElementName=btn}"></Setter>
<Setter Property="ContextMenu.Placement" Value="Top"></Setter>
```

Or Like this:

```
<Setter Property="ContextMenuService.Placement" Value="Top"></Setter>
```

The placement property worked well with right click like this if ContextMenuService.IsEnabled is not set it false. I had to set it false to make sure that the ContextMenu only worked with Left Click.

```
<Button x:Name="btn" ContextMenuService.Placement="Top">
```

Thank you!

Comment: A possible explanation would be that if the Context Menu is too large to fit *above* your `Button`, then it will be displayed somewhere else. Have you thought about this?

Comment: Thanks Mike for the response. The Context menu is not large, It just contains two buttons. It also seems to work perfectly fine when assigning in Code behind logic but doesn't seem to work with setter property in xaml.